# Convergence of Gaussian random variables

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance-matrix, convergence, graphical-model

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of 0-mean Gaussian densities on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and assume $f$ is  limit of $(f_n)$.

**Question 1** How does one determine the type of convergence by looking at the corresponding sequence of covariance matrices?

(In the set-up above, I am not specifying the type of limit on purpose. This is because in the example below, the authors just give a sequence of covariance matrices and from there seem to conclude that the sequence of the corresponding Gaussian random variables should be converging weakly. I want to understand how they connect the type of convergence of random variables to the convergent sequence of covariance matrices.)

**Background/Example**

On p. 14 of these [notes on graphical models](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/%7Esteffen/teaching/gm10/stflournotes.pdf), there is an example for instability under weak limits:

> Consider a sequence $P_{n}, n=1,2, \ldots$ of probability measures on $\mathscr{X}$ and assume that $A \perp\!\!\!\perp_{P_{n}} B \mid C$. If $P_{n} \rightarrow P$ weakly, it does not hold in general that $A \perp\!\!\!\perp_{P} B \mid C$. A simple counterexample is as follows: Consider $X=\left(X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}\right) \sim \mathscr{N}_{3}\left(0, \Sigma_{n}\right)$ with
> $$
> \Sigma_{n}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
> 1 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} & \frac{1}{2} \\
> \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} & \frac{2}{n} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \\
> \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} & 1
> \end{array}\right) \rightarrow\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
> 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 1
> \end{array}\right)
> $$
> so in the limit it is not true that $1 \perp\!\!\!\perp_{P} 3 \mid 2$. The concentration matrix $K_{n}$ is
> $$
> K_{n}=\Sigma_{n}^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
> 2 & -\sqrt{n} & 0 \\
> -\sqrt{n} & \frac{3 n}{2} & -\sqrt{n} \\
> 0 & -\sqrt{n} & 2
> \end{array}\right)
> $$
> so for all $n$ it holds that $1 \perp\!\!\!\perp_{P_{n}} 3 \mid 2$. The critical feature is that $K_{n}$ does not converge, hence the densities do not converge.

**Question 2** How should one change the sequence of covariance matrices in this example to get convergence in probability? Almost sure? In total variance?

**Question 3** Assuming that my sequence of densities is formed by computing estimates from a sequence $X_1, X_2, \dots$ with density $f_0$, does it matter for the type of convergence whether the sequence is independent? I'm mainly interested in MLE, but an explanation that applies to an arbitrary estimator would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Despite the occurrence of "variables" in your title, the first two questions do not concern (random) variables at all: they are purely about density functions.  Presumably your limit is the usual pointwise limit of functions.  In particular, without additional assumptions (about those hypothetical random variables), it's impossible to say anything about almost sure convergence.

Comment: @whuber thanks for the comment. I don't mean pointwise limit. In the example, they seem to somehow conclude that the densities converge in distribution by just presenting the sequence of the corresponding covariance matrices. I am trying to understand why this is true. (will add this now to question 1)

Comment: With (non-degenerate) Gaussian densities, these fine distinctions are irrelevant: all such densities are defined for the entirety of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and are infinitely differentiable.  There is a *huge* distinction between a sequence of RVs and a sequence of densities, though, and paying attention to that will help you sort out the underlying concepts and address your questions.

Comment: could you say more about the latter? I am very confused... Regarding the type of limit: it does matter in my case, because a few lines later the authors say that the conditional independence limits are preserved if the limit is in total variation. So I want to understand how that would affect the sequence of covariance matrices.

Comment: Some our threads on [types of convergence](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=convergence) might help you sort this out.

Comment: Thank you! @whuber